# How to modify links in multiple files with regex in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3

I need to copy the URL of a specific tag within more than 500 HTML files where the URLs are random, and put it in another but preserving all code. That is, copy the link inside the quotation marks of a `href` tag and repeat it in another tag.

For example I want to change this:

```
href="PODCAST_32_LINK" 
url: 'RANDOM_PODCAST_LINK'
```

to:

```
href="PODCAST_32_LINK"
url: 'PODCAST_32_LINK'
```

I can capture the link with the regex `[\S\s]*?` using the Find function, but I'm not sure what I can put in the Replace field.

I tried:

```
Find: href="[\S\s]*?"
Replace: url:'$1'
```

However, of course, this breaks the code, replacing the first with the second.

Comment: If this is a task that'll be done more than once I'd recommend not doing it in the editor, but instead write a little code to parse the HTML then use simple lookups to identify the specific tags, modify them then write the corrected file out. Even if it's being done once, having to do it on 500 files would make me write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**:      `(?s)(href="([^"]+)".*?url: ')[^']*`
**Replace With**: `$1$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bi5whX/1/)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `.` now matches any char including line break chars
- `(href="([^"]+)".*?url: ')` - Group 1:

  - `href="` - a literal substring
  - `([^"]+)` - Group 2: 1+ chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `url: '` - a literal substring.
- `[^']*` - 0 or more chars other than `'`.

The replacement is the concatenation of values in Group 1 (from `href` till `url: '`) and 2 (the href contents).

Comment: Perfect! It's like a magic. You saved weeks of work that I'd have to do manually. Thank u very much Wiktor Stribiżew. And I appreciate the patience and time spent explaining every detail of the code. Have a great week and all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your designed expression, if I understand the question, you might just want a capturing group here,

```
href="([\s\S]*?)"
```

and replace it with `url: '$1'` which might work then.

[Please see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/mdjIkZ/1/)

Other expressions that would likely work here are:

```
href="([^"]+)"
href="([^"]+?)"
href="(.*)"
href="(.*?)"
href="(.+)"
href="(.+?)"
```

all being replaced by:

```
url: '$1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help too, Emma. The code works. However, it replaces the first group by the second, and I needed the structure of both to be maintained, only making the link of the first one copied to the second. Anyway, thank you for the attention and the answer. Cheers!